# Deleting a pin from mapView that is created using CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, mapkit

I have a map view with custom annotations. The annotations are loaded from coreData. I would like for the user to be able to click on the annotation to edit or delete the pins. 
 I am really struggling attempting to delete only the selected annotation. I am new to programming and even newer to Core Data, so please excuse any ignorance. 
 Here is the function I am trying to make work. With this function nothing is deleted, or printed.

```
func  deletePin() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let requestDel = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Fish")

    let thisCatch = selectedAnnotation?.title
    requestDel.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    let predicateDel = NSPredicate(format: "species == %d", thisCatch!)
    requestDel.predicate = predicateDel


    do {
        let locations = try context.fetch(requestDel)
        for location in locations{
            context.delete(location as! NSManagedObject)

            self.map.removeAnnotation(selectedAnnotation!)
            print("pinDeleted")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed")
    }

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Failed saving")
    }
}
```

Here is the extension where I am trying to call deletePin()

```
extension MapViewController: ExampleCalloutViewDelegate {
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didTapDetailsButton button: UIButton, for annotation: MKAnnotation) {



    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Edit or Delete", message: "Any changes are permenate!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    let deleteDataAction = UIAlertAction(title: "delete", style: .destructive, handler: { action in

        self.deletePin()

       // self.map.removeAnnotation(annotation)
      //  print(annotation.title!)
```

Comment: Do you have any unique ways to identify each annotation? Cause if you can delete based off a specific identifier (unique name for example), you can (at worst) loop through and delete it using a comparison check

Comment: @Jay I am attempting to use the selectedAnnotation.title as the ID. this should match the title atribute in my CoreData entity. But I have no idea if this is actualy working. The commented out //print(annotation.title) gives me the title of the annotation I am trying to delete.

Comment: have you tried deleting within the same do-catch statement?

Comment: @Jay not exactly sure what you mean by the same do-catch statement. I have tried to put the do-catch into the extension with the alert and nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using this code all in the extension.

```
extension MapViewController: ExampleCalloutViewDelegate {
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didTapDetailsButton button: UIButton, for annotation: MKAnnotation) {



    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Edit or Delete", message: "Any changes are permenate!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    let deleteDataAction = UIAlertAction(title: "delete", style: .destructive, handler: { action in

        let pinTitle = self.selectedAnnotation?.title

            do{
                let request: NSFetchRequest<Fish> = Fish.fetchRequest()
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "species == %@", pinTitle!)
                request.predicate = predicate

                let locations = try self.context.fetch(request)
                for location in locations{
                    self.context.delete(location)

                    self.map.removeAnnotation(self.selectedAnnotation!)
                    print("pinDeleted")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Failed")
        }

        do {
            try self.context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Failed saving")
        }

    })
```

For my use the selectedAnnotation.title is time and date so it is a unique ID If anyone has a cleaner way of setting this up please let me know!